# finding an id in an array in mongodb (advance query)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My `expenses` collection setup is like this:

```
{
    userIds: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
    }],
    totalExpense: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
    },
    ...
}
```

Notice that the `userIds` is an array of ObjectId. `userId` will be provided through request. But `userId` is not required. If the user gives an `userId` with the request body then I have to find all the `expenses` where `userId`(from request) is in the `userIds`(in database) array. Again if the user does not provide an `userId` then I need to return all the `expenses`.

Now I need to write a MongoDB query to achieve the result.
I tried this:

```
Expense.find({ userIds: userId })
```

But it only returns some `expenses` if `userId` exists and is matched with the database. If `userId` does not exist it returns an empty array.

Comment: So, what's your issue?

Comment: Please check the last edits.